Issue with Visibility of DrawingImage in WPF Image Source
I'm encountering an issue with a DrawingImage not being visible in the designer or during run-time within a WPF application. Here's the setup:
MainWindow.xaml
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="TestDictionary.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Button>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource close_FILL0_wght400DrawingImage}"/>
    </Button>

TestDictionary.xaml
    <DrawingImage x:Key="close_FILL0_wght400DrawingImage">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,-960 V0 H960 V0 H-960 Z">
                <DrawingGroup.Transform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="960" />
                </DrawingGroup.Transform>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF000000" Geometry="F1 M960,960z M0,0z M256,-200L200,-256 424,-480 200,-704 256,-760 480,-536 704,-760 760,-704 536,-480 760,-256 704,-200 480,-424 256,-200z" />
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>

Despite setting the Source of the Image to {StaticResource close_FILL0_wght400DrawingImage}, the DrawingImage is not visible as expected.
Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this visibility issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Remove the ClipGeometry. Why do you have that at all?

I think that the clip geometry is wrong. The first V0 sets the current y value to 0. The second V0 does the same again and therefore doesn't change the current point. It probably should be V-960. If you want to declare a square, then the last H-960 is superfluous as Z closes the path anyway. Assuming that you want a square between (0, -960) and (960, 0): "M0,-960 V0 H960 V-960 Z". But we don't know what you are trying to draw. Please explain!

You could also explicitly declare a RectangleGeometry with XAML tag syntax.

You Drawing looks far too complicated. Try something like this:
<DrawingImage x:Key="close_FILL0_wght400DrawingImage">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L10,10 M0,10 L10,0">
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="2"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>

